# drop first year of data by id in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a quick way to drop an x year of data in dataframe in R. I am looking to drop the first 1 year per id. My data is ordered by id and date where date is of id is a month apart from one another. The way that I am currently thinking is somehow create a count from 1 to N for each id, then just drop N = 1 to 12, but I am wondering if there is a better method just in case my data contains some missing dates.

For example, my data might look something like this:

```
id | date
__________
 a | 2009-01-01
 a | 2009-02-01
 a | 2009-03-01
 a | 2009-04-01
 a | 2009-05-01
 a | 2009-06-01
 a | 2009-07-01
 a | 2009-08-01
 a | 2009-09-01
 a | 2009-10-01
 a | 2009-11-01
 a | 2009-12-01
 a | 2010-01-01
 a | 2010-02-01
 a | 2010-03-01
 b | 2003-07-01
 b | 2003-08-01
 b | 2003-09-01
 b | 2003-10-01
 b | 2003-11-01
 b | 2003-12-01
 b | 2004-01-01
 b | 2004-02-01
 b | 2004-03-01
 b | 2004-04-01
 b | 2004-05-01
 b | 2004-06-01
 b | 2004-07-01
 b | 2004-08-01
 c | 2007-03-01
```

and my desire output is to drop the first year of data for each id:

```
id | date
__________
 a | 2010-01-01
 a | 2010-02-01
 a | 2010-03-01
 b | 2004-07-01
 b | 2004-08-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
# attach the year (as.Date might not be needed if yours is already a date)
df$year <- format(as.Date(df$date),format = '%Y')

# attach the minimum year for each id
df$minyear <- ave(x = df$year,df$id,FUN = min)

# subset by the minyear variable
dfnew <- df[df$year != df$minyear, ]
```

**Update**

Oh I see, not data in the first year but data within a year from the first date. Using lubridate makes this easy still.

```
# add year to date
require(lubridate)
df$addyear <- ymd(df$date) %m+% years(1)

# find minimum cutoff date for each id
df$mindate <- ave(x = df$addyear,df$id,FUN = min)

# subset by mindate
dfnew <- df[df$date >= df$mindate, ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified your code to get the desired result, which I'll post below since it doesn't format well in comment form

Answer (score 0):

easy peasy:

```
df = read.csv(text="id,date
 a,2009-01-01
 a,2009-02-01
 a,2009-03-01
 a,2009-04-01
 a,2009-05-01
 a,2009-06-01
 a,2009-07-01
 a,2009-08-01
 a,2009-09-01
 a,2009-10-01
 a,2009-11-01
 a,2009-12-01
 a,2010-01-01
 a,2010-02-01
 a,2010-03-01
 b,2003-07-01
 b,2003-08-01
 b,2003-09-01
 b,2003-10-01
 b,2003-11-01
 b,2003-12-01
 b,2004-01-01
 b,2004-02-01
 b,2004-03-01
 b,2004-04-01
 b,2004-05-01
 b,2004-06-01
 b,2004-07-01
 b,2004-08-01
 c,2007-03-01")


library(lubridate)
df$date <- ymd(df$date)

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(year(date) > min(year(date)))
#>    id       date
#> 1   a 2010-01-01
#> 2   a 2010-02-01
#> 3   a 2010-03-01
#> 4   b 2004-01-01
#> 5   b 2004-02-01
#> 6   b 2004-03-01
#> 7   b 2004-04-01
#> 8   b 2004-05-01
#> 9   b 2004-06-01
#> 10  b 2004-07-01
#> 11  b 2004-08-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Code I put together that achieves my desired results using ARobertson's code to get started

```
df$year <- format(df$date, format = '%Y')
df$minyear <- ave(x = df$year,df$id,FUN = min)

d <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(df$minyear))
d$year <- d$year + 1
df$cutoff_date <- as.Date(d)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
dfnew <- df[df$date >= df$cutoff_date, ]
```